# Better Errors Gem not working in local browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, better-errors-gem

I have tried all the things from this link to try to solve this, but it doesn't work

[Better Errors Gem not working in local browser, no errors visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26152964/better-errors-gem-not-working-in-local-browser-no-errors-visible)

This is what I have in my gem file

```
    group :development, :test do
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'coderay'
gem 'erubis'
gem 'better_errors'
gem 'binding_of_caller'

  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 4.0'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'capistrano', require: false
  gem 'capistrano-rvm', require: false
  gem 'capistrano-rails', require: false
  gem 'capistrano-bundler', require: false
  gem 'capistrano3-puma', require: false
  gem 'webmock', require: false
  gem "rails-erd"
  gem 'byebug'
end
```

I'm running this on my mac http://localhost:3000/

I have set set 
`config.consider_all_requests_local = true` in config/environments/development.rb

when I add this line in development.rb

```
BetterErrors::Middleware.allow_ip! "0.0.0.0/0"
```

I get this error

```
development.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>': undefined method `allow_ip!' for BetterErrors::Middleware:Class (NoMethodError)
```

I also did a bundle install

This is my development.rb

```
    Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = false

  # Adds additional error checking when serving assets at runtime.
  # Checks for improperly declared sprockets dependencies.
  # Raises helpful error messages.
  config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true



config.consider_all_requests_local = true

  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {host: 'localhost:3000'}
  config.action_mailer.default_options = {from: ENV['EMAIL_USER']}
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      address: 'smtp.gmail.com',
      port: 587,
      domain: ENV['DOMAIN'],
      authentication: 'plain',
      enable_starttls_auto: true,
      user_name: ENV['EMAIL_USER'],
      password: ENV['EMAIL_PASSWORD']
  }

  Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin/"



end
```

Comment: Did you try to restart rails?

Comment: I did stop and start the local server.

Comment: Could you, please, show all contents of your `config/environments/development.rb`? Btw, if you use `better_errors` only on localhost, you don't need that `allow_ip!` line.

Comment: I updated the question with the contents of development.rb

Comment: Please, add the line `BetterErrors::Middleware.allow_ip! "0.0.0.0/0"` there.

Comment: Is there a specific place I add this line?  I get this error when I add it development.rb:35:in `block in <top (required)>': undefined method `allow_ip!' for BetterErrors::Middleware:Class (NoMethodError)

Comment: Well, it's just need to be inside `Rails.application.configure do` block. Also, it may still be the chance, that your app is still running if you use spring. Run `spring stop` prior starting your rails.

Comment: I put in the Rails.application.configure do block.  The last part of your message got cut off.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90702/discussion-between-alexey-shein-and-user2974739).