# Gem 'better_errors' not working Rails 5.0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I installed gem `better_errors` version `2.1.1` for my ruby on rails application. However, I still get the same old debug page. I have also installed the gem `binding_of_caller`. I even installed the three gems which as shown as runtime dependencies for `better_errors`, namely `erubis`, `coderay` and `rack`(see the gem page [here](https://rubygems.org/gems/better_errors)). All this to no avail.

I have also tried other solutions, one is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26153035/4554700). All this to no avail.

I am using `Ubuntu 16.04`, `rails 5.0.0.1` and `ruby 2.3.1p112`.

Comment: Did you do `bundle install` and restart the server after that? Do you use spring? Try restarting spring too.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev YES!

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I am using puma for development.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev It's not working with spring as well. Restarted both puma and spring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are not testing with just a [routing error / 404 exception](https://github.com/charliesome/better_errors/issues/243#issuecomment-56996880), as that [will no longer end up triggering `better_errors`](https://github.com/charliesome/better_errors/issues/220).

Best way to confirm whether it's working or not would be to put some undefined variable in a controller action and then hitting that URL.

Comment: I couldn't have ever imagined this could be the error. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You installed the gem in development?

```
'group :development do
  gem "better_errors"
end'
```

I just added better_errors to my Rails 5 app and its working fine.

Comment: Thanks, the issue is solved, I installed it in `group development` itself.